# Hibernate column refer the total of details

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a table `order` and a table `order_items` (one `order` has many `order_items`).
I want to have a column in order entity that refers to the sum of the column values in order items. is there a way to do it in Hibernate? At each update or insert of related order items, I want to recalculate the value in order table. 
For example:

Order a: has 3 records in `order_items` with value 1, 2, 3. The column total on order must be 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with the [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation and a subselect doing the adding.

Note that the value will only get updated when the entity gets reloaded from the database.

If you want it to update during changes to the entity in your java code you have to implement that in your entities with plain old java code.