# Hibernate Formula with join

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

i have an entity order and an entity order_items ( 1->n relation).
I want a field in order that table that show the sum(quantity) of related order items. These are my entities:

```
    @Entity(name="ORDERS")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name="order_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order", cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems=new ArrayList();



@Entity(name="ORDER_ITEMS")
public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name="order_item_id")
    private long id;

    @Column (name="quantity")   
    private int quantity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order;
```

I want a new field in Order entity that show the total quantity ( sum of quantity of the childs).
I've tried to add the field in order but it not works

```
@Formula("select sum(oi.quantity) from ORDER_ITEMS oi where oi.order_id= order_id)")
private int totalQuantity;
```

Can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate column refer the total of details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051748/hibernate-column-refer-the-total-of-details)

Comment: This is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051748/hibernate-column-refer-the-total-of-details. Don't create multiple questions in different ways for the same problem. This won't help anyone.

Comment: is different.. in previous post i ask the method to have this result -> Formula. This post is about formula and his behavior

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution

```
    @Formula("(select sum(oi.quantity) from ORDER_ITEMS  oi where oi.order_id= order_id)")
private int totalQuantity;
```

Comment: Why this works:  Note the additional parenthesis in this answer vs the missing parenthesis in the question.  The paranethesis surrounding the entire select statement.  `@Formula("(select...`