# How to set custom aliases for JOINs in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I do use `CriteriaBuilder` and construct a query with some JOINs. I wanted to use an alias for them, because in the root entity I need to create a `@Formula` that can access the columns from the JOINs.

I used the `SQLExtractor` to check what are the generated aliases and used them in `@Formula` and that did work. Unfortunately, the aliases may be different since are auto generated, so I wanted to use a custom alias instead.

```
var tableB = root.join(ATTRIBUTE, JoinType.LEFT);
tableB.alias("customTableBAlias");
```

However, if we check the SQL generated with `SQLExtractor` the custom alias is not there.

I checked the implemntation of Hibernate and I do see a field `correlationParent` which is null, and then it calls `super.getAlias()` maybe it's caused by that? Are there any suggestions how I can make it work?

Comment: Formula is built into the entity mapping and should not require anything specific from individual queries - it has to work with a findById query without joins, and fetches when the entity is associated to other entities. If your formula needs a join, you might need to add the table as a secondary table, or use a separate query for the formula ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/44065056/496099 )